# Filter Data from table work but after search again not found nothing [Angular,Pagination,Table]

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, filter, emit

I have table with pagination. I build a function that take the object and filter it and then show in table the result.

The problem is when I search again the old data from the object was removed in the first search and when I search again is not found me.

this is my code and my sort function:

```js
export class TaxreportsComponent implements OnInit {

  public taxList: Array<Tax>;
  public page: number;
  public currentPage: Array<Tax>;
  public totalItems: number;

  constructor(private service: CompanyService) {
    this.totalItems = 0;
    this.currentPage = [];
    this.taxList = [];
    this.page = 1;
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getTaxList((data) => this.onGetTaxList(data));
  }
  onGetTaxList(data) {
    this.taxList = data;
    this.currentPage = this.taxList.slice(0, 10);
    this.totalItems = this.taxList.length;
  }
  pageChanged(event) {
    const startItem = (event.page - 1) * event.itemsPerPage;
    const endItem = event.page * event.itemsPerPage;
    this.currentPage = this.taxList.slice(startItem, endItem);
  }

// Sort the data and change the table
  sort(searchWord) {
    const data = this.taxList.filter(item => {
      return item.type === searchWord;
    });
    this.onGetTaxList(data);
  }
```

And this is my html:

```js
<app-home-menu (filteEvent)="sort($event)" ></app-home-menu>
<div class="table-container">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr class="table-nav">
        <th scope="col">Year</th>
        <th scope="col">Type</th>
        <th scope="col">HP</th>
        <th scope="col">CompanyName</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <ng-container *ngFor="let tax of currentPage">
        <tr>
          <td>{{tax.year}}</td>
          <td>{{tax.type}}</td>
          <td>{{tax.cid}}</td>
          <td>{{tax.company}}</td>
        </tr>
      </ng-container>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div class="table-footer">
  <pagination class="pagination" nextText=">" previousText="<"  [totalItems]="totalItems" (pageChanged)="pageChanged($event)"> </pagination>
</div>
</div>
```

I need to find a way for each search that the original object initialization first then search again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using just one variable (`taxList`) for data. when you get actual data from service, you set it. and when you filter it, you set it again. so actual data will be lost.

You can instead introduce another variable (`filteredTaxList`) for filtered data.

Now at first, when you get the actual data from service, you should store it on `taxList` , and set `filteredTaxList` to it.

then when you change the filter, you set `filteredTaxList` from `taxList`.

then you should use the new variable (`filteredTaxList`) in whole code, like for pagination and etc.

```
export class TaxreportsComponent implements OnInit {

  public taxList: Array<Tax>;
  public filteredList: Array<Tax>;
  public page: number;
  public currentPage: Array<Tax>;
  public totalItems: number;

  constructor(private service: CompanyService) {
    this.totalItems = 0;
    this.currentPage = [];
    this.taxList = [];
    this.filteredList= [];
    this.page = 1;
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getTaxList((data) => this.onGetTaxList(data, true));
  }
  onGetTaxList(data, isOriginal) {
    if(isOriginal) this.taxList = data;
    this.filteredtaxList = data;
    this.currentPage = this.filteredtaxList.slice(0, 10);
    this.totalItems = this.filteredtaxList.length;
  }
  pageChanged(event) {
    const startItem = (event.page - 1) * event.itemsPerPage;
    const endItem = event.page * event.itemsPerPage;
    this.currentPage = this.filteredTaxList.slice(startItem, endItem);
  }

// Sort the data and change the table
  sort(searchWord) {
    const data = this.taxList.filter(item => {
      return item.type === searchWord;
    });
    this.onGetTaxList(data, false);
  }
```